# Why does abseil automatically add the namespace "absl::lts_2020_02_25"

Tags: c++, abseil

I built [abseil](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/archive/20200225.2.tar.gz) with cmake, Finally I found out that abseil added a namespace "absl::lts 2020_02_25" which I didn't want, e.g.

```
0000000000020a2c T absl::lts_2020_02_25::StrAppend(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::AlphaNum const&)
```

I use below cmd to build the abseil library

```bash
cd abseil-cpp
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 ..
cmake --build . --target all

nm absl/strings/libabsl_strings.so -C | grep StrAppend
```

Comment: What problem is this causing you? I'd guess that that namespace is not visible when using the library and is added for ABI compatibility

Comment: when I link the abseil library, it will prompt not found “absl::StrAppend”

Comment: What are you linking with the abseil library?  What that thing built against this version of abseil?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where the real question is about how to solve a specific linker error.

Comment: Not familiar with abseil, but it's likely there is some logic to be able to use multiple versions of the lib in parallel. The `absl` namespace probably contains multiple namespaces one of which is an inline namespace for you to be able to use the `absl` namespace to refer to the current version without having to specify the full namespace including `lts_2020_02_25`... The linker error could be caused by incorrect headers being linked. How does your cmake project link abseil?

Comment: please show a [mre] including the full text of the error message. My guess would be you haven't enabled c++11 in your program so the inline namespaces are getting disabled